# Zend-server: What is 'wasted memory' and why will it cause Zend accelerator to restart?

Tags: zend-framework, caching, memory, apc

We are experiencing problem using Zend Server on a CentOS linux box. Within a day, our large cache (1gig of memory space reserved) uses about 100megs of cached entries, but almost 500megs of it is 'wasted memory.

When the percentage of wasted memory exceeds 'max_wasted_percentage', the cache is 'restarted', which means all existing cache entries are cleared. Not what we want, obviously.

So, what is this 'wasted_memory' and how can it be avoided?

-- Edit: Perhaps it is the sum of all the memory used by files that have been cached, but never requested afterwards.

Comment: Possibly more appropriate on server fault?

Comment: 1. it will be used when 'realfree' is ended; 2. read http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=22690&forum=45

Answer (score 0):

in simple words - wasted_memory is free memory. like in filesystem, when file is deleted, its only MARKED as deleted, but not 'filled with zeros'

Comment: Would that mean that this memory will be used by the caching mechanism when it runs out of 'real' free memory (simply overwrite it)? How exactly is determined when memory is 'wasted'? What is the rule set for this?